# If $f (t) = |t - 2|$, find $f (-t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

Why question:

> If $f (t) = |t − 2|$, find $f (−t)$

has result: $|t + 2|$?

I don't understand it.

Comment: Would it be easier if you first found $f(-u)$, and then changed $u\mapsto t$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation $f(-t)$ says to take the expression for $f(t)$ and change all $t$ to $-t$. You get
$$
f(-t) = |(-t)-2| = |-t-2| = |-(t+2)| = |t+2|.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(-t)=|(-t)-2|=|(-1)(t+2)|=|-1||t+2|=|t+2|$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(-t) = |-t - 2| = |-1||t + 2| = |t + 2|$.

Another way to describe the answer is:

$t + 2$ if $t \geq -2$ and $-t - 2$ if $t < -2$

because, when these two separate answers are combined, it gives the definition of $|t + 2|$.